# How come jobParameters cannot be found in ItemProcessor using annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am having issues using the job parameters in my item processor. At this time, the code is basically setup like: [How to get Job parameteres in to item processor using spring Batch annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737209/how-to-get-job-parameteres-in-to-item-processor-using-spring-batch-annotation) but I am receiving an error at runtime. Also, please note that my example code does use some spring integration for processing.

```
[ERROR] [restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimFileMessageToJobRequest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'job': Error creating bean with name 'importClaimJob' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importClaimJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimStep1' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimJob' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importClaimJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimStep1' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.Application.main(Application.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimJob' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importClaimJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimStep1' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importClaimJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimStep1' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importClaimStep1' defined in class path resource [com/healthcloud/batch/config/ClaimBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:381)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.importClaimStep1(<generated>)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration.importClaimJob(ClaimBatchConfiguration.java:185)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.CGLIB$importClaimJob$6(<generated>)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ecf5444c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.importClaimJob(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'importClaimStep1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimLineItemProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientName': Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:381)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.claimLineItemProcessor(<generated>)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration.importClaimStep1(ClaimBatchConfiguration.java:196)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.CGLIB$importClaimStep1$7(<generated>)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ecf5444c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.healthcloud.batch.config.ClaimBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b3b47e8.importClaimStep1(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Using the example at [How to get Job parameteres in to item processor using spring Batch annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737209/how-to-get-job-parameteres-in-to-item-processor-using-spring-batch-annotation), I have the following code. One would think this would be a simple cut and paste and then be on my way. I am using jobParameters elsewhere just fine, but it definitely fails in the ItemProcessor.

ClaimBatchConfiguration:

```
... 
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ClaimBatchConfiguration {

...

    @Bean
    public ClaimLineItemProcessor claimLineItemProcessor() {
            return new ClaimLineItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importClaimJob() {    
        return claimJobBuilderFactory.get("importClaimJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(claimListener()).flow(importClaimStep1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step importClaimStep1() {    
        return claimStepBuilderFactory.get("importClaimStep1").<ClaimLine, ClaimLine> chunk(1)
                .reader(claimFileReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION)).processor(claimLineItemProcessor())
                .writer(claimLineWriter()).faultTolerant().retryLimit(retryLimit)
                .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class).skipLimit(1) // default is 0
                .skip(Exception.class).build();
    }
```

ClaimFileMessagetoJobRequest.java:

```
...
@Component
public class ClaimFileMessageToJobRequest implements ApplicationContextAware {
...

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "claimInputChannel", outputChannel = "commonJobGateway")  
    public JobLaunchRequest messageToRequest(Message<File> message) {
        logger.info("Load Claim Started at " + DateFormat.getCurrentDateTime());

        String[] fileNameParts = message.getPayload().getName().split("[_]");

       // handle error
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString("clientName", fileNameParts[1]);

        logger.debug("Job Paramaters: " + jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

        JobLaunchRequest request = new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

        return request;
    }

...
}
```

ClaimLineItemProcessor.java:

```
@Scope("step")
public class ClaimLineItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ClaimLine, ClaimLine> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['clientName']}")
    private String clientName;

    // client name getter and setter here

    @Override
    public ClaimLine process(ClaimLine claimline) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("Current Client Name" + clientName);

    // bunch or work to really do
        return claimline;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `@Scope("step")` should be on the bean definition (in the `ClaimBatchConfiguration`), not on the class itself.  Also, as an FYI, you can use `@StepScope` as a short cut (also on the bean definition).

Comment: Interesting enough, I had just tried that when your answer came in and I still got the error. From testing: @StepScope works. @Scope("step") fails. @Scope(value="step") fails.

Comment: In response to my own comment, the difference seems to be the proxy which @StepScope sets. I tested using @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) and sure enough it worked.